# Two Qudit custom gate error in Cirq

Tags: cirq, quantum-state

I am trying to build two qudit CX (d-dim) gate.
[image]

and getting below error.
[image]

There is no issue in the unitary matrix.
Please suggest to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_qid_shape_` should return `(self.d, self.d)` instead of `(self.d * self.d,)`. You're currently asking or one $d^2$-level object instead of two $d$-level objects.

If you specify qid shape, you don't have to specify num qubits.